# Can i push downloaded npm dependencies to gitlab package registry

Tags: node.js, jenkins, npm, gitlab, npm-package

I am creating a Jenkins pipeline to build an AngularJS project in an air-gapped environment. For this purpose, I would like to push the required dependencies to the GitLab package registry. Is it possible to do that, or are there any other options available to resolve the required dependencies in an air-gapped environment?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

you can publish and consume npm packages directly from GitLab's package registry

by adding the registry URL to your .npmrc file.

```
npm config set registry https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/packages/npm/
```

Comment: but how can i push downloaded dependencies to the gitlab package registry?